# Can we use Conditional Compilation in VBA to declare variable inside a function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to refactor an old macro which are failing in newer MS-Office 365 version.

For kernel32 and User32 I have declared the function variable at the top like:

```
#If Vba7 Then 
  Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr
#Else
  Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long
#EndIf
```

But can I use conditional compilation inside the function as well like:

```
Function CopyToClipboard(ByVal Msg as String)
#If VBA7
Dim hWindow as LongPtr
#Else
Dim hWindow as Long
#End If
.
.
End Function
```

It's working in some system but `copyToclipboard` is still failing in some system.
I have seen several copy clipboard function for VBA in StackOverflow but they are still failing in some system.

Any input would be greatly helpful as how to resolve this problem.

**Update:**
What I ended up doing to fix the problem was I enclosed my declarations in the following condition handling both VBA7 and VBA6 and also 32-bit and 64-bit system using Win64 conditional argument.

```
#If Vba7 Then 
  #If Win64 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr
  #Else
    Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long
  #End If
#Else
  Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long
#EndIf
```

I copied the VBA6 declaration for 32-bit system because I think the LongPtr was not getting resolved properly and the macro was failing.
Now its working perfectly in every system.

Comment: Yes, you can use conditional compilation to declare variables like that. If it fails on some systems, then most likely you have your API declarations wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the following resources:

- [Understanding conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-conditional-compilation)
- [#If...Then...#Else directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-directive)
- [Compiler constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/compiler-constants)

This works not only for declaration of functions (where it is mostly used) but also in normal code.

You can for example even use it for …

- debuging modes like:

  ```vb
  #Const conDebug = 1   ' Declare public compilation constant in Declarations section. 

  Sub SelectiveExecution() 
      #If conDebug = 1 Then 
          ' Run code with debugging statements. 
      #Else 
          ' Run normal code. 
      #End If 
  End Sub
  ```
- writing Mac/Windows specific code

  ```vb
  #If Mac Then 
      '. Place exclusively Mac statements here. 
  #ElseIf Win32 Then 
      '. Place exclusively 32-bit Windows statements here. 
  #Else 
      '. Place other platform/fallback statements here. 
  #End If
  ```

The example you showed is the perfect and correct way to go for this.

---

If you are not sure about your function declarations check the official reference:
[Programming reference for the Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api).

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked. I have updated my answer with the solution I ended up doing.